# Change Bottom Tab Bar based on state in React Navigation with navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to change the bottom tabs on the screen based on what features are enabled. This feature list is populated via a login API call.

Currently I have the following:

```
const TabRouteConfig = {
  Home: DashboardScreen,
  FeatureA: FeatureA,
  FeatureZ: FeatureZ,
};

const TabNavigatorConfig = {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  order: [
    'Home',
    'Feature A',
  ],
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  lazy: true,
};

const TabNavigator1 = createBottomTabNavigator(
  TabRouteConfig,
  TabNavigatorConfig,
);

// Set the tab header title from selected route
// https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-stack-contains-a-tab-navigator-and-you-want-to-set-the-title-on-the-stack-header
TabNavigator1.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { index, routes } = navigation.state;
  const { routeName } = routes[index];

  return {
    headerTitle: routeName,
  };
};

const TabNavigator2 = createBottomTabNavigator(
  TabRouteConfig,
  {
   ...TabNavigatorConfig,
   order: [
      'Home',
      'Feature Z',
   ]

);

TabNavigator2.navigationOptions = TabNavigator1.navigationOptions;

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: props => (props.screenProps.hasFeature ?
      <TabNavigator1 /> : <TabNavigator2 />
    )
  },
})

const WrappedStack = props => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Stack
      screenProps={{ hasFeature: props.hasFeature }}
    />
  </View>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    ...props,
    hasFeature: state.hasFeature,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(WrappedStack);
```

This mostly works - it dynamically switches between `TabNavigator1` and `TabNavigator2` based on `hasFeature`, but it no longer honors the `navigationOptions` placed on the TabNavigators and the `headerTitle` is not set.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does WrappedStack has properties of navigation i.e. props.navigation

Answer (score 7):

It's an antipattern to render more than one navigator simultaneously as the navigation states of those navigators will be completely separated, and you will not be able to navigate to one from another.

You can use `tabBarComponent` option to achieve what you want. Hope you can get the idea from below example:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  TabRouteConfig,
  {
    tabBarComponent: ({ navigation, ...rest }) => {
      const filteredTabNavigatorRoutes = navigation.state.routes.filter(route => isRouteAllowed(route));
      return (
        <BottomTabBar
          {...rest}
          navigation={{
            ...navigation,
            state: { ...navigation.state, routes: filteredTabNavigatorRoutes },
          }}
        />
      );
    },
  },
);
```

NOTES:

- You don't have to install `react-navigation-tabs` separately. It is automatically installed with `react-navigation` 2.0.0+.
- `isRouteAllowed` is the function which returns `true` or `false` based on whether to show that route or not. Make sure to only check the top level routes in that object.
- `TabRouteConfig` should contain all possible tabs, and this logic only hides the route from the TabBar visually. So, you can still programmatically navigate to all routes. Therefore, you might need additional logic in each of those screens to decide whether to render them based on `hasFeature`.